# How to parse $2^{1+2^3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

I'm fairly comfortable with arithmetic and high school math overall, but I'm having trouble being 100% sure that $2^{\large {1+2^3}}$ should be parsed as `2^(1+(2^3))` and not as `2^((1+2)^3)`, because I've heard that

> One must evaluate the base of an exponent before it is raised to the exponent.

As I understand that is actually true and the only way to support the second alternative is to claim that the power is $1+2^3$ (instead of $2^3$ alone) and that its base is $1+2$.

Can anyone confirm that the correct interpretation is `2^(1+(2^3))` and that it yields $512$?

Comment: $$2^{1+2^3}=2^{1+8}=2^9=512$$

Comment: Yes, the answer is $512$. The base of the exponent in $1+2^3$ is just $2$. Had there been brackets as $(1+2)^3$, it would have meant $3^3$

Comment: You are correct. Exponents take precedence over addition.

Comment: This is a well established convention. Powers (or exponents) are evaluated first and indeed, in $1+2^3$ the only power is $2^3$, there's no way to argue that the base is $1+2$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your work is indeed correct.

Note also: $2^{\large(1+2^3)} = 2^1\cdot 2^{\large(2^3)} = 2 \cdot 2^8=2\cdot 256 = 512$, just as an exercise in working with exponents.

This can be useful, e.g., if you are working with $3^{\large(2+2^2)} = 3^{2 + 4}= 3^2\cdot 3^4 = 9\cdot 81= 729.$

Which ever you find easiest to do in various such examples, if one has $a^{b+c}$, one can add $b+c = d$, then calculate $a^d$, or, equivalently, one can multiply $a^b\cdot a^c$.